# How to check if enough specific elements are in a list?

Tags: python, regex, list, loops, while-loop

I am trying to check if at least five items in my list have the following format: `r"P\d+:Q\d+"`. So, these are accepted:

```
P14:Q52
P32:Q65
P1000:Q23423
:
:
etc.
```

I have a list of cell ranges like below:

```
mcr_coord_lst = [mcr.coord for mcr in worksheet.merged_cells.ranges]

mcr_coord_lst
['P58239:Q58239',
 'P58234:Q58234',
 'P58235:Q58235',
 'P58236:Q58236',
 'P58237:Q58237',
 'P58238:Q58238',
 'P58229:Q58229',
 'P58230:Q58230',
 'P58231:Q58231',
 'P58232:Q58232',
 'P58233:Q58233',
 'P58224:Q58224',
 'P58225:Q58225',
 'P58226:Q58226',
:
:
 'A123:Q324234',
:
:
]
```

I set up a counter and add to the counter if the item in my list matches `pq_columns = re.compile(r"P\d+:Q\d+")`. If the counter >= 5, then I break the loop and return `'Yes'`. However, this result is returning `'Yes'`for all of the items in my list and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
counter = 0
is_in = False
while is_in == False:
    for item in mcr_coord_lst:
        if pq_columns.match(item):
            counter += 1
            if counter >= 5:
                print('Yes')
                is_in = True
        else:
            print('No')
            break
```

This code outputs:

```
Yes
Yes
...
Yes
Yes
Yes
:
:
```

Can you help me fix my code? *Or* do you recommend another way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Don't print the results until the loop has competed. You can `break` when you've found 5. An `for/else` might be helpful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension we can try:

```py
lst_filter = [x for x in mcr_coord_lst if re.search(r'^P\d+:Q\d+$', x)]
if len(lst_filter) >= 5:
    print("list is valid")
else:
    print("list is not valid")
```

Comment: Both yours and @Daweo's solution works! Thank you! Do you think your way of list comprehension is a more efficient way of achieving my end goal? That is, is my logic of using counters and looping through elements of my list pythonic and efficient?

Comment: For example, I commented below that Using list comprehension reduces the code to two lines but it loops through the entire mcr_cood_lst whereas the way I originally had goes through one element at a time and stops if the counter reaches 5. Is this the right way to think about the solution?

Comment: @Josh Your assumptions are correct, and if you want the most efficient way to do this, you should, as you have mentioned, use a loop and simply stop after finding 5 matches.  Also, the loop option in the other answer also saves storage space, as my answer requires allocating an entirely new list to store the filtered result (which you don't even need).

Answer (score 0):

You are changing is_in which affect outer loop (while) but not inner loop (for), add `break` to also terminate inner loop that is

```
counter = 0
is_in = False
while is_in == False:
    for item in mcr_coord_lst:
        if pq_columns.match(item):
            counter += 1
            if counter >= 5:
                print('Yes')
                is_in = True
                break
        else:
            print('No')
            break
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you think this is the correct (efficient) way to go about this? Using list comprehension reduces the code to two lines but it loops through the entire ```mcr_cood_lst``` whereas the way I originally had goes through one element at a time and stops if the counter reaches 5. 

I know just to write code that works, but I also want to practice good pythonic coding and strong software engineering fundamentals. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Josh I just make your code working, if you are interested in ehnancement proposals I suggest you put *working* code at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

run this code. note that there is no need to use `while` in this code!

```
counter = 0
for item in mcr_coord_lst:
    if pq_columns.match(item):
        counter += 1
        if counter >= 5:
            break

if counter >=5:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```